# How to stop particular instance of X server?

Tags: xorg

I know this sounds ridiculous at first glance, but I started X session from root with

```
# X :1 vt08 &
```

So I guess `sudo stop lightdm` would be overkill. How can I stop that instance of X server without stopping main X session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find the PID of the running X instances and kill the one you don't want. For example:

```
$ pgrep -a X
3885 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -background none -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-M5IpFT/database -nolisten tcp vt7
$ kill 3885
```

Your output will have more than one PID since you are running multiple instances, so make sure you pick the right one.

Comment: Actually, I found the correct PID in initial output (i.e. when you start something, it prints PID like `[nnnn]`). But when it's lost, your solution is awesome!